# Using SWC with Bazel

Tags: bazel, swc-compiler, bazel-rules-nodejs

I'm trying to compile my TS files to JS with SWC in Bazel. I'm unfortunately unable to use the rules_js library (which has rules_swc), so I need to hand roll it. So far I have:

```
load("@npm//@swc/cli:index.bzl", "swc")

SRC_FILES = glob(["**/*.ts"])

swc(
    name = "compile_ts",
    outs = [s.replace(".ts", ".js") for s in SRC_FILES],
    args = [
        "$(location %s)" % s
        for s in SRC_FILES
    ],
    data = SRC_FILES,
)
```

I get

> Successfully compiled 96 files with swc.

but no output and the following error

> ERROR: output {file} was not created

for each src file I passed in. How do I get the compiled files to output to the bazel-out folder so they can be used as inputs to other rules?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bazel's `--output_base` startup option to override the default output base directory. For example, `bazel --output_base=/tmp/bazel/output build x/y:z`

Please refer the Bazel open source doc for [output-directories](https://bazel.build/remote/output-directories).